# React APP opens 2 tabs when configured with BROWSER and BROWSER_ARGS on server start

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I've created a React APP listening on default port of 3000. Locally, I'm also running Nginx on port 8000 as a reverse proxy to several backend services, including both the ReactAPP and a remote GraphQL server. So when I start the server I would like the browser to open up on localhost:8000 rather than the default localhost:3000.

Following the advanced configuration here:  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration I've configured my dev script in package.json with both the BROWSER and BROWSER_ARGS variables:

```
"dev": "BROWSER=google-chrome BROWSER_ARGS=http://localhost:8000 react-scripts start",
```

This will correctly open a browser tab for localhost:8080, but it will also open a tab for localhost:3000. How do I configure react-scripts to open only the page I want?

I'm using version 3.4.0 of react-scripts

Answer (score 0):

I think the usage of BROWSER_ARGS is wrong, because as documentation said it pass that as an argument, so whats happening is your brower is going to port 3000 then this argument is passed which is another URL or port, and so does 2 tabs.

Use PORT instead I think as it is mentioned in the documentation to change the port

definition of PORT below
"By default, the development web server will attempt to listen on port 3000 or prompt you to attempt the next available port. You may use this variable to specify a different port."

Comment: Unfortunately, adding PORT=8000 conflicts with the Nginx server already running on port 8000.